# matplotlib: ylabel on the secondary y-axis with manual tick placing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have a y-label on the secondary y-axis in matplotlib. I'm aware, that `twinx()` almost does the trick like so:

```
ax2 = twinx(ax1)
ax2.set_ylabel('some thing')
```

However, my `ax1` has a non-standard tick placing and the duplicate `ax2` does not copy that property, so that I would have to explicitly adjust the ticks again.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: do you want to have the same y-axis ticks on both of them?

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't found, how to label both axes on a single subplot, I found a solution for an axes matrix:

```
fig, axs = subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axs[0, 0].set_ylabel('on the left by default')
axs[0, 1].yaxis.set_label_position('right')
axs[0, 1].set_ylabel('...now on the right y-axis')
```

Hope this helps other people, too.